# Number is equal to nth power of summation of its digits

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I am working on problem from code wars. Following is the question

> The number $81$ has a special property, a certain power of the sum of its digits is equal to $81$ (nine squared). Eighty one ($81$), is the first number in having this property (not considering numbers of one digit). The next one, is $512$. Let's see both cases with the details
>
> $8 + 1 = 9$ and $9^2 = 81$
>
> $512 = 5 + 1 + 2 = 8$ and $8^3 = 512$
>
> We need to make a function, power_sumDigTerm(), that receives a number n and may output the n-th term of this sequence of numbers. The cases we presented above means that
>
> power_sumDigTerm($1$) == $81$
>
> power_sumDigTerm($2$) == $512$
>
> Happy coding!

Only possible way I can think to solve this problem is by using brute force approach. But it is too time consuming Is there any mathematical theory I can apply to solve this problem.

Comment: You can always remove certain cases. For example if your number is odd and the sum of digits is even then this cannot happen, similarly if it is the other way.

Comment: Similarly, if the sum of digits is a multiple of 5, but the number does not end in 5 or 0 , such cases maybe removed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys but it is still not good enough to improve the performance. For the big values of n(like above 20) it will take a lot of time and steps.

Answer (score -1):

Denis,

try to calculate all powers (2 to 180) ^ (2 to 63), sort this and remove duplicates (3^4 == 9^2).

Now you can go in the list of powers and check if powering the sum of the digits will be the original number. I.e: use your brute force only for this items.

I finished the challenge with total calculation time of 52ms from server.
But to achieve this I reduced the range to fit the problem.

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Actually, @mlc, this is the answer.
I just did't write the solution here. Two reasons: 1st I don`t know which language he is using. 2nd the goal of the challenge is to challenge him. Not copy and past.

Comment: Well, he asked if there is a mathematics theory to solve this... 
The theory basically is: get all the powers, since you know that your solutions are inside this group. Than you apply the conditions to the known possible answers, and check all that solve the problem.